# Utilizar Alertify.js en Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, alertify

Estoy haciendo un CRUD simple, pero quiero que al momento de Crear un nuevo Empleado, Actualizarlo o Eliminarlo me salte un mensaje con Alertify, se que esta odannyc-Alertify que se instala con Composer pero igual no me funciona, y al momento de instalar Alertify con el composer me salta este mensaje.

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
>   Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

Esta es la parte del controlador para actualizar y quiero que se muestre ese mensaje

```
    /**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);
    $employee->fill($request->all());
    $employee->save();
    alertify()->success('USER WAS UPDATE.')->delay(6000)->position('bottom right');
    return $this->show($id);
}
```

Comment: Asi no, declara tu funcion alertify en tu html entre etiquetas <scrip> </script>, o colocalo en un archivo js, linkeado a tu vista. lo que enviaras a la vista sera el mensaje y condiciones con un if si el mensaje exite se imprime la alerta

Comment: Te da algún error `alertify`? Verificaste que el paquete esta en el `composer.lock`?

Comment: debería salirte algo como esto `"name": "odannyc/laravel-alertify",
            "version": "1.0.0",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.

Ese error que te marca la consola es porque tienes un paquete que ha sido abandonado **phpoffice/phpexcel** y te recomiendan usar el nuevo paquete **phpoffice/phpspreadsheet**.

Sobre *odannyc-Alertify* para que funcione

1. Ejecutar `composer require odannyc/laravel-alertify` en la consola. (verificar en `composer.lock` si se encuentra el paquete).
2. En el archivo `app.php` ubicado en `config/app.php` debes agregar

   - En la sección de `'providers' => [
         odannyc\Alertify\AlertifyServiceProvider::class,
     ];`
   - En la sección de `'aliases' => [
     'Alertify' => odannyc\Alertify\Alertify::class,
     ];`
3. En tu vista `HTML` (si lo necesitas disponible en cualquier vista), debes incluir en `resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php` lo siguiente

   - `@include('alertify::alertify')`
   - `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alertifyjs/alertify.js/v1.0.10/dist/js/alertify.js"></script>`

Yo realice la prueba en un proyecto nuevo.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    alertify()->success('Probando Alertify directamente desde web.php');
    return view('welcome');
});
```

[image: Prueba de Alertify]

En el `composer.lock` encuentro el paquete así:

> "name": "odannyc/laravel-alertify",
>   "version": "1.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

El código que tienes escribo según la documentación que hay en el repositorio de Github esta bien, googleando el error parece que es un paquete del composer que esta deprecado

> Unfortunately, this dependency got deprecated, as one sees when running `composer update`:
>
> `Package phpoffice/phpexcel is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead.`
>
> Is someone already working on an update to upgrade to phpoffice/phpspreadsheet instead?
>
> Best regards

ref del error [en github](https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle/issues/131)